# How to open quill image uploader programmatically?

Tags: file-upload, quill, image-upload, ngx-quill, react-quill

I have a two toolbar in quill.

1. Quill toolbar
2. Custom toolbar

I need to put the image tool in the custom toolbar but the problem is that quill is only allowed the addHandler for its own toolbar so I need to open the quill image uploader programmatically when the user clicks on my image.

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Quill toolbar with `quill.getModule('toolbar')` which will expose the format handlers. This will also work with custom handlers that you've added to the Quill toolbar.

```js
// ... set up quill stuff

// get the quill toolbar
let toolbar = quill.getModule('toolbar')

// call the image handler
toolbar.handlers.image()
```